# Error after migrating spring boot to 3 in update query containing enum field

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

Have updated hibernate-types & hypersistence libraries as per other docs-

```
implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-60:2.21.1'
implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60:3.5.1'
```

and excluded  - `spring.jpa.properties.hypersistence.utils.enable_types_contributor=false`
so that types doesn't get registered automatically.

Attribute in the entity:

```
 @Column(name = "status")
 private Status status;
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

But getting error -

> Cannot
> invoke "java.lang.Class.getName()" because "this.enumClass" is null]
> with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.lang.Class.getName()" because "this.enumClass" is null  at
> org.hibernate.type.EnumType.verifyConfigured(EnumType.java:386)   at
> org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeSet(EnumType.java:392)    at
> com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType.set(PostgreSQLEnumType.java:70)  at
> com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType.set(PostgreSQLEnumType.java:29)  at
> com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.ImmutableType.nullSafeSet(ImmutableType.java:105)

Comment: Issue was with the query - had updated to :#{#status.name()} instead of status = :status

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76145055/cannot-invoke-getjdbcvaluebinder-because-jdbcmapping-is-null